# Ayuda con el metodo MERGE de sqlserver pero solo para unos datos

Tags: sql-server, sql

Bien resulta que tengo tabla tabla con historico de 2017 a la fecha (2020); solo que los datos para para el ejercicio en curso cambian cuando se hace un enlace a otros sistema, la cuestion aqui es como puedo solo actualizar los datos del ejercicio 2020, sin que merge borre los de años anteriores.

este es el merge que estoy usando.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MtoContratos-Obtener-Contratos-SAIB]
  @tblContrato ContratoSai READONLY,
  @tblDetalle DetalleContratoSai READONLY
 AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT OFF;

BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    BEGIN TRY

    /*================================================================================================================
    MERGE DE LA BASE DE DATOS
    ================================================================================================================*/
    MERGE MtoContrato with (holdlock) AS Destino
USING (Select NO_CONTRATO,RFC_PROVEEDOR,MONTO_ORIGINAL,MONTO_CONTRATO,MONTO_MINIMO,
        NO_LICITACION,EVENTO_COMPRANET,ESTADO_CONTRATO,NUM_PROVEEDOR,FECHA_EMISION,
        FECHA_INICIO,FECHA_TERMINACION,FECHA_FIRMA from @tblContrato) as Origen
 ON (ltrim(rtrim(Origen.NO_CONTRATO))=ltrim(rtrim(Destino.NoContrato)))

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    
    update set

    Destino.NoContrato= origen.NO_CONTRATO,
    Destino.MontoOriginal=origen.MONTO_ORIGINAL,
    Destino.MontoContrato=origen.MONTO_CONTRATO,
    Destino.MontoMinimo=origen.MONTO_MINIMO,
    Destino.NoLicitacion=origen.NO_LICITACION,
    Destino.EstadoContrato=origen.ESTADO_CONTRATO,
    Destino.NumeroProveedor=origen.NUM_PROVEEDOR,
    Destino.FechaEmision=origen.FECHA_EMISION,
    Destino.FechaFirma=origen.FECHA_FIRMA,
    Destino.FechaInicio=origen.FECHA_INICIO,
    Destino.FechaTerminacion=origen.FECHA_TERMINACION,
    Destino.RfcProveedor=origen.RFC_PROVEEDOR,      
    Destino.EventoCompranet=origen.EVENTO_COMPRANET                         

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

   INSERT 
       (NoContrato,MontoOriginal,MontoContrato,MontoMinimo,NoLicitacion,
        EstadoContrato,NumeroProveedor,FechaEmision,FechaFirma,FechaInicio,
        FechaTerminacion,RfcProveedor,EventoCompranet)
   VALUES
       (NO_CONTRATO,MONTO_ORIGINAL,MONTO_CONTRATO,MONTO_MINIMO,NO_LICITACION,
        ESTADO_CONTRATO,NUM_PROVEEDOR,FECHA_EMISION,FECHA_FIRMA,FECHA_INICIO,
        FECHA_TERMINACION,RFC_PROVEEDOR,EVENTO_COMPRANET);

        

    COMMIT TRANSACTION 

    END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 

  DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000),
      @ErrSeverity int 

 SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
     @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY() 

 RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1) 

 END CATCH 
        
 END
```

La situación seria:

- como pongo la consulta para que solo afecte a los registros 2020,
- que no eilimine los registros de años anteriores, pero que elimine aquellos del 2020 que ya no vengan en el enlace.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tener dos condiciones `when not matched`: `by source`, `by target`.  Utiliza una para realizar la inserción y otra para realizar el borrado de los datos que ya no te interesan:

A la cláusula `when not matched` puedes agregarle condiciones para borrar solamente los registros que son del 2020 y dejar los de otros años que estén en la tabla. No me queda claro cuál es el campo que contiene la *fecha* de interés, pero suponiendo que sea `FechaFirma`, la sentencia merge quedaría algo así:

```
merge MtoContrato with (holdlock) AS Destino
using (select   NO_CONTRATO, RFC_PROVEEDOR, MONTO_ORIGINAL, MONTO_CONTRATO
              , MONTO_MINIMO, NO_LICITACION, EVENTO_COMPRANET, ESTADO_CONTRATO
              , NUM_PROVEEDOR, FECHA_EMISION, FECHA_INICIO, FECHA_TERMINACION, FECHA_FIRMA 
         from @tblContrato) as Origen
   on (ltrim(rtrim(Origen.NO_CONTRATO)) = ltrim(rtrim(Destino.NoContrato)))
 when matched then
      update 
         set   Destino.NoContrato = origen.NO_CONTRATO
             , Destino.MontoOriginal = origen.MONTO_ORIGINAL
             , Destino.MontoContrato = origen.MONTO_CONTRATO
             , Destino.MontoMinimo = origen.MONTO_MINIMO
             , Destino.NoLicitacion = origen.NO_LICITACION
             , Destino.EstadoContrato = origen.ESTADO_CONTRATO
             , Destino.NumeroProveedor = origen.NUM_PROVEEDOR
             , Destino.FechaEmision = origen.FECHA_EMISION
             , Destino.FechaFirma = origen.FECHA_FIRMA
             , Destino.FechaInicio = origen.FECHA_INICIO
             , Destino.FechaTerminacion = origen.FECHA_TERMINACION
             , Destino.RfcProveedor = origen.RFC_PROVEEDOR
             , Destino.EventoCompranet = origen.EVENTO_COMPRANET                         
when not matched by target then
     insert (  NoContrato, MontoOriginal, MontoContrato, MontoMinimo
             , NoLicitacion, EstadoContrato, NumeroProveedor, FechaEmision
             ,FechaFirma, FechaInicio, FechaTerminacion, RfcProveedor, EventoCompranet)
     values (  NO_CONTRATO, MONTO_ORIGINAL, MONTO_CONTRATO, MONTO_MINIMO
             , NO_LICITACION, ESTADO_CONTRATO, NUM_PROVEEDOR, FECHA_EMISION
             , FECHA_FIRMA, FECHA_INICIO, FECHA_TERMINACION, RFC_PROVEEDOR, EVENTO_COMPRANET)
when not matched by source
 and Year(Destino.FechaFirma) = 2020 then
     delete
;
```